# User Customizable Form - Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, sqflite, textformfield

I wish to create a Interactive, User-Customizable Form in Flutter - where the User can pick, drag and drop Data Fields from a List provided and then save the Form as a Template.
The Data Fields will be from a Sql Database in the backend and Form will get stored as a template for future reference and use.

This will be for a Finance App where the User would be investing amounts in multiple Options like Fixed Deposits, Bonds, Shares, SIP etc.

So, the list of Fields could be:

```
Start Date:
Close Date:
Amount Deposited:
Frequency : 
Maturity Amount: 
Rate of Interest:
```

and so on..

Instead of giving the User fixed forms for each of these investments, if the User is allowed to pick the necessary fields and create a template for himself, it might be more interactive.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think it's not a Good user experience since it a Finance App for investment.

But I could still be done not with drag and drop property because it doesn't look formal for an investment app, but with a checkbox!

list all fields in a checkbox, any field that user checks will be automatically added to The Form.

Comment: Thanks @david for the revert. This is a good option. I was thinking of  the Long Press Drawable feature with which the user could move the  fields into the form to create one.

Comment: nice option  @gputhige